# Image loader weighting algorithm

Tags: algorithm, math, distribution, formula

I am building an image preloader and am attempting to create a weighting function to determine which image to load next.

Here is a quick breakdown of my needs:

I have an array of images in successive order. I have a variable weighting which must have a value between -1 and 1.

- A weighting of -1 means to load only images which have an index lower than the previously loaded image.
- A weighting of 1 means to load only images which have an index greater than the previously loaded image.
- A weighting of 0 means to evenly distribute the loading of images.
- A decimal weighting e.g.(0.6) means to load images with an index greater than the previous image 60% of the time and those lower 40% of the time.

The weighting always starts at 0. The weighting on each update is provided with the index of a new image to view, and the index of the last viewed image.

I wish to modify the weighting on each image view taking into account:

- whether the new index is greater than the old index (the user has
  gone forward)
- the number of images below the given index versus the number above.
- the previous weighting (The greater the distribution leans towards one end of the scale the slower the weighting increments towards that end and the greater it increments towards the other).

I hope I made the problem clear enough. Does anyone know of an algorithm or formula which can help provide this functionality?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i started thinking like this:

```
function weighting(not_yet_preloaded_indices_array, 
                   current_index,
                   previous_index,
                   previous_weighting) {
    count_of_all = not_yet_preloaded_indices_array.length()
    count_of_next = count_bigger(not_yet_preloaded_indices_array, current_index)
    count_of_previous = count_of_all - count_of_next

     if (count_of_previous = 0) {
        return 1
    } else if (count_of_next = 0) {
        return -1
    }

    if (current_index >= previous_index) {
        direction = 1
        modifier = count_of_next / count_of_all
    } else {
        direction = -1
        modifier = count_of_previous / count_of_all
    }

    return (previous_weighting + direction * modifier) / 2
}
```

but i doubt the weighting would benefit users any more than simple preloading, e.g.:

```
1. preload 1 next image  (if not already preloaded)
2. preload 1 previous image  (if not already preloaded)
3. preload 5 or 10 next images  (only the ones not already preloaded)
```

where `next` is the chosen direction (either bigger or smaller indices)

Comment: Thanks for your input, the problem I have with this algorithm is that say the weighting reaches 0.9 after the user repeatedly views images with a higher index, as soon as the user goes to an image with a lower index the weighting suddenly favours to preload images with a lower indices. I would want it to still favour images with higher indices (based on the users pattern still more likely to occur) just less so.

Comment: Just realised I was implementing it wrong and the previous_weighting should stop the weighting flipping signs...  The benefit comes becomes I have over 90 images and the user is free to take any path through them they want (can jump to 20 from 3 say), I load a number of images simultaneously and this helps me to figure out how to distribute the loading of them so the user is less likely to see a loading bar.

Comment: just make sure mobile phone users that are paying for each MB won't download a lot of unseen images and then hate you :)